# Why not any linearly independent set of vector is basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I think this is a question asked several times but I am still confusing about some detail. Many of answer for this question give an example such that give an basis $V = \{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$, then removing one element from $V$, the rest of set $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_{n-1}\}$ is still a linearly independent set but no longer a basis. However this is where I am confused, for simplicity, restrict V to be a basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$. If we remove $v_3$ from $V$, the set $\{v_1,v_2\}$ can form a plane, which should be a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$. Then according to our question, the $\{v_1,v_2\}$ may not be the basis of this plane subspace, why this is true?

Comment: It is a basis of its span (the plane). But it is not a basis of the original space ($\Bbb R^3$).

Comment: That isn’t the claim being made; the claim is that the result is no longer a basis of $V$ specifically. On the other hand, every linearly independent set of vectors is a basis of its span.

Comment: and the two comments above can be combined into an answer.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I understand it is not a basis for original space, but if the new set is the basis of its span, this example does not support the tile statement that not any linearly independent set is a basis.

Answer (score 1):

A basis is a maximal linearly independent set, which means it must span the entire space to be a basis. Since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is three dimensional it requires three basis vectors. While two linearly independent sets do form a basis for a plane since they are not a maximal linearly independent set since I can find a third independent vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. This means it cannot be a basis.

Comment: "This means it cannot be a basis [of $\mathbb R^3$]" (brackets mine).  Else, "This means it cannot be [its] basis" (brackets mine).  I allow the latter because your sentence before it refers to $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: I am still confused, for sure by removing one element, the new set is not a basis for original space, but in my example,  if the new set form a basis for the plane, this example does not support the tile statement that not any linearly independent set is a basis.

Comment: @SnowMax the plane is a proper subset of the vector space. A basis must span the entire vector space.

Comment: So a plane is not always a subspace for $\mathbb{R^3}$. Could you give me an example that two linear independent vector do form a plane but the plane is not a subspace?

Comment: @SnowMax A proper subset means it is a subset and is missing some of the original elements. The only plane that isn't a proper linear subspace of a higher dimensional space is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Could you be more specific about "missing some of the original elements". Did you mean the zero vectors? From my knowledge, to be a subspace requires 3 preparty, the zero vector, close under scalar multiplication and close under vector addition. But we could obtain the zero vector by multiplication 0 on the rest of set, and the closure property should still hold since it is a subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: @SnowMax a proper subset will be missing *some* element but which is immaterial. To be a vector space the zero vector must be included so it can't be one of them. Say for example we consider the plane  spanned by $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then the vector $(0,0,1)$ is not in the plane but is in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and cannot formed as a linear combination of the basis vectors for the plane.

Comment: I think this is really not a good example, $\{(1,0,0) , (0,1,0) \}$ is not a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$, but this set do actually form the xy-plane, and any plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ that pass through the origin is a subspace, so $\{(1,0,0) , (0,1,0) \}$ is the basis for a subspace(xy-plane).

Comment: @SnowMax that's correct. They are a basis of the subspace, but not the entire space. $(0,0,1)$ is linearly independent of those two vectors and not in the plane. Therefore the plane is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. A basis is always defined with respect to the space it is in. Changing the space can change the dimension, and so can change what is an isn't considered a basis in that space.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto David's comment with an example, $\{\ (1,0,0),\ (0,1,0) \}$ *is* the basis of a plane, but no linear combination of $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ equals $(0,0,1)$, which means that $\{\ (1,0,0),\ (0,1,0) \}$ is not a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: OK, I understand it is a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$, but could we consider the plane being a subspace, then the $\{ (1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is the basis for this subspace. So even removing an element still give a basis for subspace, than this example shouldn't prove the title statement.

Comment: “Ok, I understand it is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$”. You understand *what* is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: That is a typo, I re-state what I am confused at here, by removing an element from basis set, the new set is not a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$ for sure, but the new set is the basis for the plane. So the problem arise at here, if the plane is a subspace for $\mathbb{R^3}$, than, this removing element example does not support the the original statement that "not any linearly independent set is a basis". So, when using this removing element example to argue the original statement, it either mean the new set is not a basis for plane, or plane is not a subspace?

Comment: The statement, "not any linearly independent set is a basis" is bad English. It could mean, $(1)$ It is not true that every linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. $(2)$ It is not true that every linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a basis of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. $(1) $ is true, as we have seen. I think $(2)$ is false, although I'm not 100% certain. But I think your original statement is statement $(1)$. Removing element example *does* support Statement $(1)$. Do you think it doesn't, and if so, why not?

Comment: OK, yeah this might be the wording problem, I agree the original statement is not rigorous enough. So if the meaning is (1), no problem this is true for sure. However, I view the original statement as (2), And this is what I actually want to ask at here. So, I am also not sure this is either true or false, could you find some example that two linearly independent vector form a plane, but the plane does satisficed the 3 preparties of a subspace?

Comment: you mean, "...but the plane does **not** satisfy the 3 properties of a subspace?" I believe the answer is **no**, you can't find two such linearly independent vectors. the span of *any* two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will always be a plane going through the origin, and any plane going through the origins is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. See here for details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672287/proof-about-subspaces-in-r3

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I have too much typo. So I see, the (2) is at least not true for $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: Yes. See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l20Rt9-rJKw  "Plane without Origin is not a Subspace of R3 Not Closed Under Addition and Multiplication". See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472105/why-a-%E2%84%9D2-subspace-in-%E2%84%9D3-should-be-a-plane-through-the-origin

Comment: Anyway, you're asking quite a lot of questions. So let's end this discussion and you can always ask more questions on the site...